# adjective + compliments

Tags: collocation

> Give my warm/heartiest/best compliments to him.

I have been told that the sentence above is wrong. But I don't understand why. 
The correct answer was

> Give my compliments to him.

Why can't adjectives like the ones above be used before *compliments*?

Answer (score 0):

Comments don't support the long ngram link. :(

The version without adjectives seems more idiomatic ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+*_ADJ+compliments%2Cmy+compliments%2Cmy+regards%2C+my+*_ADJ+regards&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cmy%20%2A_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmy%20best_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20respectful_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20sincere_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20affectionate_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20kindest_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20sincerest_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20personal_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20warmest_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20humble_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20particular_ADJ%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20compliments%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cmy%20%2A_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmy%20best_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20kindest_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20warmest_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20warm_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20affectionate_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20sincere_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20respectful_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20highest_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20cordial_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmy%20fondest_ADJ%20regards%3B%2Cc0)). However it is purely a matter of idiomacy of the collocation, not grammar, of course you can put an adjective in front of noun, grammar-wise.

So to answer the literal question, adjectives can be used before the word compliment. It doesn't seem to be very idiomatic. I cannot explain why.

Comment: Uh… Helmar, have you ever sent anyone your "best wishes"?

Either way, can you explain any grammatical difference between "wishes" and "compliments"?


That said, neither "warm" nor "best" really works with "compliments"… I can't really explain why but that's not a grammatical point.

Also it would be less unusual to say Give him my (whatever) compliments… Again I can't really explain why but native speakers  would expect to hear either "Give him my compliments" or perhaps "Give my compliments to Tom (or Dick or Harriet)"